# pyqt changing item after selection

Tags: pyqt

So I have an AbstractItemModel and after I click the Load button, I want the selected item to change colours and boldness.  How do I do that?

I tried something like `QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red)))` but none of my items changed colour.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AbstractItemModel is just that: Abstract. It is meant to be subclasses, which means you would have some custom type of implementation.

But if you were using QStandardItems, you can just set its [foreground](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qstandarditem.html#setForeground) color, and its [font](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qstandarditem.html#setFont):

```py
item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red))
font = item.font()
font.setBold(True)
item.setFont(font)
```